# Como acessar os valores em um banco de dados no realtime database do Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, realtime-database

Estou executando o seguinte código:

```
    var dadosCarro = firebase.database().ref('carro');
    dadosCarro.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      console.log(data)
    });
```

Como resposta no console, tenho:

```
{-NitWx_oNdW8uFnvmsVh: {…}}
-NitWx_oNdW8uFnvmsVh:
nome: "Onix"
marca: "Chevrolet"
ano: "2021"
```

Como posso acessar o valor do atributo nome, que neste caso é "Onix" e atribuir em uma variável?

Answer (score -3):

```
const key = Object.keys(data)[0];
const nome = data[key].nome
```